# Can't declare new array within' multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I have this code:

```
<?php
foreach($arrs_menu as $show_submenu => $k){
    $get_parent_menus[$k['donemen']][] = array(
        $k['id_page'] => $k['id_page']
    );
}
?>
```

The problem here, is that I'm trying to put a new array within `$get_parent_menus[$k['donemen']]`, so when I put this `[]`, in order to NOT REPLACE the current array, and creating a new one, it gives me an error: `[]` operator not supported for strings in.

If I remove it, I get it okay, but only once value is set correctly.

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Strange code and not complete. Pls provide a complete example.

Comment: It would seem that `$get_parent_menus[$k['donemen']]` is a string and not an array.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that `$get_parent_menus[$k['donemen']]` is a string and not an array.

What you could do, is put the original value in an array if it is not an array already:

```
if (!is_array($get_parent_menus[$k['donemen']]))
{
  // trying to keep the original value although I don't know where the key should come from...
  $get_parent_menus[$k['donemen']] = array(array('some_key' => $get_parent_menus[$k['donemen']]));
}
$get_parent_menus[$k['donemen']][] = array($k['id_page'] => $k['id_page']);
```